# Roscore is not running

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error when I run roscore:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/bin/roscore", line 62, in <module>
    import roslaunch
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    import rospkg
ImportError: No module named rospkg
```

I have installed fuerte and now have installed hydro side by side...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148466/roscore-is-not-running/) by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) on 2014-04-07**:
yes I tried almost all of them.. Still not able to get the answer...
Any guesses what it could be?

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-09-21**:
did u solve it ?? I have the same problem :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks people... The problem was ros hydro python path was the problem..
Set your python path correctly as ros hydro relies a lot on python.
I didnt have problem with fuerte... However hydro has

---

Originally posted by [jennifer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2259/jennifer/) with karma: 43 on 2014-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Google returns a few threads about the same/similar issues. I'd suggest you might want to check the answers suggested in some of those first.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the record, I had the same problem with WinROS hydro, and I was missing some Python dependencies : SetupTools-0.6c11 and WinROS-python-build-tools.

---

Originally posted by [AldurDisciple](https://answers.ros.org/users/22188/aldurdisciple/) with karma: 11 on 2015-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1